# Is there some common context API for multiple MUI FormControl elements?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a form that consists of multiple MUI inputs. As of my understanding, each form input control should be wrapped by an FormControl element which provides context like (error state, required, variant etc.) for the underlying Label, Inputs and FormHelperText components. E.g. the TextField component is a convenience component where this has already been done for me.

But is there any API that can provide this context for multiple FormControl elements inside a form?

```
<form>
  <SomeContextProvider disabled={true} variant="filled" size="small" fullWidth>
    <TextField label="Field 1" />
    <TextField label="Field 2" />
    <TextField label="Field 3" />
  </SomeContextProvider>
</form>
```

In the code snippet above the TextField elements (which are FormControls under the hood) would consume the props of SomeContextProvider. Is there anything out there in the MUI library or do I have to code this myself?